# Batch Program executes on a certian date?

Tags: date, time, batch-file, execute, schedule

I've been trying to get a **batch** to start another batch on a certain date. (specified)
I've tried all that I can think of. TIMEOUT does not work for this. Any suggestions?
EDIT: I am sorry I didn't include enough information. by "batch" I meant to say batch, as in the language. I need to write a script with the language of **batch** to execute on a desired date. Say If I wrote this code in batch...

```
@echo off
:start
start notepad.exe
pause >nul
goto start
```

... and I wanted it to execute automatically on a specied date, such as November 25th, how would I go about doing so? Thank you for somewhat understanding.

Comment: Downvoted because the question lacks information. Which programming language? For which purpose? What exactly is "all I can think of"?

Comment: Please also include operating system. (Linux vs. Windows vs. ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infinite loop will waste too many system resources. Task Scheduler is a good choice.

```
schtasks /create /tn "My App" /tr C:\test.bat /sc once /st 00:00:00 /sd 11/25/2013 /ru System
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry I could not post results as I have had computer issues (hardware). This appears to have worked for the task I need. Now I just need to redo it. With the new hard drive and all.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `Task Scheduler` to do the job - that's what it was built for.

You could try

at 23:30 /every:1,4,8,14,16,23,28 "yourbat.bat"

To run `yourbat.bat` at 23:30 (11:30pm) on the date(s) following the `/every:` (run each month) or many other options - see

```
at /?
```

from the prompt and be prepared to experiment a little.

But if you want to run on a specific day without using task scheduler (although `AT` simply schedules a job...) then you might add

```
if not "%date%"=="whateverdateyouwant" goto :eof
```

at the start of `yourbat.bat` code (and the target date must be in the same format as the date shown on a`echo  %date%` instruction

But there are endless possibilities - like having a list of dates/times/processes in a file and matching these against the current date/time and using

```
if "%date%"=="%%A" if "%time%" gtr "%%B" start "" %%C
```

Where the precise construct depends on a more concrete definition of what you are doing and specification of the date and time formats you are using.

Comment: Thank you, I will try "if not "%date%"=="date" goto :a" I will report back if it works (I will have to wait until that date)